# Append HTML code not working while repeating the action in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to append HTML codes (which is being called through ajax), to a section on dropping the element, while doing so I'm able to append on first drop event but while repeating the same drop event again I'm unable to add the HTML code. Also I want both the element to be sortable so I'm calling a sortable function at the end.

I followed the following shopping cart tutorial available link in http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/Geupm/1/

Here's my Jquery code:

```
nitsbuilder.init = function () {
    var navmenu= $('ul.nitseditormenu').find('li').find('ul').find('li');
    navmenu.draggable({
        connectToSortable: "nitsbuilder.editarea",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",            
    });

    nitsbuilder.editarea.droppable({
       drop: function (event, ui) {
                nitsbuilder.dropeventhandler(ui.draggable, ui.offset);
       }
    }).sortable({
        revert: true
    });
}();

nitsbuilder.dropeventhandler = function ($item, $position) {
    var nits_id = $item.data('nitsid');
    var i = 0;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: dropurl,
        data: { nits_id: nits_id, _token: token},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (nitsbuilder.editarea.find('[data-nitsid]').length > 0) {
                nitsbuilder.editarea.children('[data-nitsid]').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).offset().top >= $position.top) {
                        $(data.htmlcode).insertBefore($(this));
                        i = 1;
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            }
            if (i != 1) {
                nitsbuilder.editarea.html(data.htmlcode);
                var datanits = nitsbuilder.editarea.find('[data-nitsid]').length;
                console.log(datanits);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please find the minimal code for the question as ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cf1m724j/2/))

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Please share [mcve] so that we can check what's the issue.

Comment: It seems that you will need to re-initialize the draggable() and droppable() functions after you append the new results, so they also get the event! Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315422/reinitialize-jquery-ui-droppable-after-adding-elements) may help!

Comment: @TJ: Included the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cf1m724j/) link in the question.

Comment: @NitishKumar I thought you had an answer to this same question the other day. Same code appears in the last 3 questions you've asked. You might want to mark some as answered.

Comment: @NitishKumar It's not clear what is not working. I did make some minor adjustments (removed `fixed` position for `page-content-wrapper` class. Now when I drag one or the other into the red square, it's doing what it should: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/kqaxxyf3/

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for the updates, I've already marked answer to my previous questions. Still got a bug to fix to your JSFiddle, as you can see when `row-12` is dragged into the red square, it appends twice the HTML code, rest all functionality is exactly as required.

Comment: It appears that `dropeventhandler` executes twice.

Answer (score 0):

You should unbind and bind draggable after your action, ex. creating element. I recomend to use class selector.

1removing funcionality

$( ".selector" ).draggable( "destroy" );

2 add again

$(".selector").draggable(..what you want...);